# I've tried to use the command pairs = list(itertools.combinations(nn[:4], 2)) on python but keep getting errors. I've read up but still don't get it

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I've tried the command `pairs = list(itertools.combinations(nn[:4], 2)`, in various different ways and I keep getting errors. The most recent way I've tried is `list(itertools.combinations(g.nodes([None:4:None]),2)`. How else can I pair nodes not including 4?

I've tried the command `pairs = list(itertools.combinations(nn[:4], 2)`, in various different ways and I keep getting errors. The most recent way I've tried is `list(itertools.combinations(g.nodes([None:4:None]),2)`. How else can I pair nodes not including 4?

Comment: What errors, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.combinations` is doing exactly what you're asking of it, either A) your input data needs filtering or B) your output data needs filtering.

If I assume your data is completely random, and the goal is to ignore and filter out any case of the number 4:

```
import itertools
import random
input = [random.randrange(1,5) for _ in range(10)]
pairsA = list(itertools.combinations([each for each in input if each != 4], 2))
pairsB = [(x,y) for x,y in itertools.combinations(input, 2) if x!=4 and y!=4]
print(pairsA)
print(pairsB)
```

But that's just a best stab as your code does not run, and you left out vital information like what your errors are, what your goal is, and what `nn` and `g` inputs are defined as. So I took my best guess here since I cannot comment ;).